# Running filebeat on docker

Tags: windows, docker, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, filebeat

i'm trying to install elk and filebeat on docker, well i uploaded the image of elk and it worked i can go to the kibana dashboard and view elastic ,...
Now I want to install filebeat image so i followed the documentation bellow , the image is pulled but when I want to run filebeat setup command i got an error.

Documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/running-on-docker.html#running-on-docker

This is the command i used:

```
docker run docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:8.1.2 setup -E setup.kibana.host=kibana:5601 -E output.elasticsearch.hosts=["elasticsearch:5601"]
```

This is the error I get:

*Exiting: couldn't connect to any of the configured Elasticsearch hosts. Errors: [error connecting to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch:9200: Get "http://elasticsearch:9200": lookup elasticsearch on 192.168.65.5:53: read udp
172.17.0.2:41384->192.168.65.5:53: i/o timeout]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you accessing kibana service ? is your elasticsearch running on http://elasticsearch:9200 ? if you are running it in localhost then try to see if its running at http://localhost:9200. Change the docker command to appropriate host values.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.

I I have corrected the command, 

```
docker run docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:8.1.2 setup -E setup.kibana.host=http://localhost:5601 -E output.elasticsearch.hosts=["https://127.0.0.1:9200"]
```
But i got this error

Comment: Exiting: couldn't connect to any of the configured Elasticsearch hosts.Errors:[error connecting to Elasticsearch at https://127.0.0.1:9200: Get "https://127.0.0.1:9200":dial tcp
127.0.0.1:9200: connect: connection refused]docker run docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:8.1.2 setup -E setup.kibana.host=http://localhost:5601 -E output.elasticsearch.hosts=["https://127.0.0.1:9200"]Exiting: couldn't connect to any of the configured Elasticsearch hosts.Errors:[error connecting to Elasticsearch at https://127.0.0.1:9200:Get "https://127.0.0.1:9200": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9200: connect: connection refused]